# Create chain of keys from string

Tags: php

Suppose, i have the fallowing json:

```
{
    "foo.bar": 1
}
```

and i want to save this like this:

```
$array["foo"]["bar"] = 1
```

but i also can have more than 2 "parameters" in string. For example:

```
{
    "foo.bar.another_foo.another_bar": 1
}
```

and i want to save this same way.

```
$array["foo"]["bar"]["another_foo"]["another_bar"] = 1
```

Any ideas how can i do that in case that i don't know how many parameters i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from the nicest solution, but I've been programming all day so I'm a little tired, but I hope it gives you something to work off, or at least a working solution for the time being.

Here's the IDEone of it working: [click](https://ideone.com/BBJ84u)

And here's the code:

```
$json = '{
    "foo.bar": 1
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);


$data = array();
foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
    $keys = explode('.', $key); 
    $data[] = buildNestedArray($keys, $value);
}

print_r($data);

function buildNestedArray($keys, $value) {
    $new = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (empty($new)) {
            $new[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            array_walk_recursive($new, function(&$item) use ($key, $value) {
                if ($item === $value) {
                    $item = array($key => $value);
                }
            });
        }   
    }

    return $new;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => Array
                (
                    [bar] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Wasn't sure whether your JSON string could have multiples or not so I made it handle the former.

Hope it helps, may come back and clean it up a bit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Then build a foreach loop to break apart the keys and pass them to some kind of recursive function that creates the values.

```
$old_stuff = json_decode($json_string);
$new_stuff = array();
foreach ($old_stuff AS $key => $value)
{
  $parts = explode('.', $key);
  create_parts($new_stuff, $parts, $value);
}
```

Then write your recursive function:

```
function create_parts(&$new_stuff, $parts, $value)
{
  $part = array_shift($parts);
  if (!array_key_exists($part, $new_stuff)
  {
    $new_stuff[$part] = array();
  }
  if (!empty($parts)
  {
    create_parts($new_stuff[$part], $parts, $value);
  }
  else
  {
    $new_stuff = $value;
  }
}
```

I have not tested this code so don't expect to just cut and past but the strategy should work. Notice that $new_stuff is passed by reference to the recursive function. This is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following trick for "reformatting" into json string which will fit the expected array structure:

```
$json = '{
    "foo.bar.another_foo.another_bar": 1
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$new_json = "{";
$key =  key($decoded);
$keys = explode('.', $key);
$final_value = $decoded[$key];
$len = count($keys);

foreach ($keys as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == 0) {
        $new_json .= "\"$v\"";
    } else {
        $new_json .= ":{\"$v\"";
    }
    if ($k == $len - 1) $new_json .= ":$final_value";
}
$new_json .= str_repeat("}", $len);

var_dump($new_json);   // '{"foo":{"bar":{"another_foo":{"another_bar":1}}}}'

$new_arr = json_decode($new_json, true);

var_dump($new_arr);
// the output:
array (size=1)
'foo' => 
 array (size=1)
  'bar' => 
    array (size=1)
      'another_foo' => 
        array (size=1)
          'another_bar' => int 1
```